# Telnet C++ or SSH Program on Launch

Tags: c++, ssh, telnet

I am wondering if someone can provide me with a couple c++ functions that would allow me to send and receive data over a telnet port.

I've also heard that I can create a program, and have it run via SSH, this would be preferred just because of the security benefits of SSH, are there any samples out there?

Update:
What I want to do, is create a console program users could use remotely via SSH or telnet.  I am a C++ programmer.

Update 2:  I know I was vague, I am creating an inventory system that I want to be accessible to our employees via SSH or telnet.  I will be using sockets, and will often display data to the user via (telnet or through ssh) and accept input from them.  I will have to implement sockets, and send data and receive data I know, is there a library for this?

Comment: Telnet and SSH are protocols.  If you want to use them, you'll need to use sockets (e.g. Berkeley Sockets, Winsock, etc) and follow the protocol for hand-shaking for either one.  Without more details about what you want, this question is way too vague.

Comment: Do you mean that your users will Telnet or SSH to a server and run the program there?

Comment: From your edit, all that is needed to create a program that can be run from telnet/ssh/rlogin/etc is to create a console program on a system that has those servers running (most Linux distributions have at least 1 of those configured by default).  There is nothing special about running a command line program via telnet vs running it from the console of the machine itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you are asking here.

You can execute a remote program via:

```
ssh <user>@<machine> "<command>"
```

(Provided you have prepared a passphrase-less pubkey authentication; you'd be asked for a password / passphrase otherwise. The very first invokation will also require user input as SSH wants to verify the fingerprint of the remote machine.)

You could then capture the output of that command line (which is equivalent to the output  of the remote command, unless ssh itself belches an error) via the usual means.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously dont believe you want to implement telnet and SSH protocol all by your handwritten code!! That would be too difficult for you.

What I think you want to do is to "**Run a command remotely**". is it?

If yes then you you would need to execute the command as told by DevSolar but you will need to generate SSH keygen to be installed so that it doesnt ask for password at the prompt.

Else write an expect script.

Comment: From your edit it seems like you want to create a console based application with your backend code doing the above mentioned thing. Then I guess you will have to consider doing programming with ncurses also.